# Saving Multiple Embedded OLE objects to target folder using file explorer

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook where users can embed OLEObjects. I want to extract all of these to a folder.

I came across the code below from user A.S.H. (I've tweaked slightly to my requirements but no change to the issue.) It runs, but doesn't execute the paste to the selected folder.

How can I fix this code or is there an alternative way of saving OLEobjects to a folder?

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Send()
    Dim folder As String, obj As OLEObject
    Shell "explorer " & folder, vbMaximizedFocus
   
    For Each obj In Worksheets("Emails").OLEObjects
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01") ' necessary, give it a moment
        obj.Copy
        SendKeys "^v" ' paste in explorer
    Next
    SendKeys "%fc" ' close the explorer
End Sub
```

Comment: I am afraid that the idea of copying an OLEObject in an Explorer window cannot work. Try to do that manually and you will see that the `Paste` option of the context menu is grayed out. I know how to paste a file from clipboard, but Microsoft does not allow copying of such objects outside the application. Initially you could copy some of them like 'scrap' files. Can you specify the link where such a code has been confirmed like working?

Answer (score 0):

3 things:

1. Are you sure that there are OleObjects in your sheet?
2. In the sub the variable folder is declared but you do not assign it a value, then Explorer is opened on a default path, probably "Collections" into which you cannot paste anything.
3. not all OleObjects can be pasted in that way.

Otherwise, the code works; the only essential thing is that you specify the directory where you want the files to be saved.